# what does the parameter of plot(): subplots do?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

First of all, I am sorry if some of you find this question to be silly. I am asking this because I still don't get how it works even though I have tried it and read its documentation.

For example, I write the following code:

```
 .plot(subplots = True)
```

or

```
.plot(subplots = False)
```

What does it do to the plot? and what does it mean when it is equivalent to True or False?

Comment: You're asking about Pandas DataFrame.plot() function? See: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.line.html?highlight=subplots

Answer (score 2):

I supposed you are asking about the function of Pandas, `pd.DataFrame.plot()`, so from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

> subplots : boolean, default False

> Make separate subplots for each column

So for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(3 * np.random.rand(4, 2), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns=['x', 'y'])

df.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(8, 4))

df.plot(subplots=False, figsize=(8, 4))

df
          x         y
a  0.397800  2.695104
b  1.662394  1.549103
c  2.057893  1.986597
d  2.106607  2.572737
```

**With subplots** *(subplots=True)*:

[image]

**Without subplots** *(subplots=False)*:

[image]